Using with block vs processing the file in one line
In Python, while reading the file's content, it is recommended to use the with block.
Something like below
with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    content = f.read().splitlines()

However, if I am not processing much, I can do something like below in one line, which looks more compact.
content = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8').read().splitlines()

Or call a function that does the processing.
isTheFileGood = func(open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8'))

over
with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    isTheFileGood = func(f)

Is there any advantage of one over another? Say in terms of garbage collection etc.?

Use the context manager approach for clarity and efficiency (of resource management)

Using the with statement when reading files in Python is generally recommended because it ensures that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised during the process.
When you use the one-liner without the with statement, the file isn't being explicitly closed in the same way. Technically, the file will be closed when it's garbage collected by Python but it's good practice to explicitly manage resources, especially when dealing with files.
So, in terms of advantages, the with statement offers better resource management, clearer code intention and reduces the likelihood of resource-related issues as compared to the one-liner approach.

Please remember to only format text that is clearly code as code.

If you don't use with, the opened file will not be closed manually. I.e., unless you remember to explicitly call close on the opened file handle, you'll have a leak.
If the only reason you want to avoid calling with is to make the code shorter, you'll probably offset this shortness by adding an explicit close call.
To phrase it differently - unless you have a really good reason to want to control when exactly the file handle is closed, you should probably just use with and allow Python to clean up after you.

The main use of with throughout Python is not to create an object or scope, but to ensure that things are cleaned up when the scope is exited. If you see with open_database(...) as db: ..., you can be sure that the database is flushed and closed when it is done.

Isn't that what I answered?

You were talking about with open. I was expanding it to say with, no matter what follows, is used for its cleanup, not its initialization.  In general, getting rid of a with, no matter what the circumstances, isn't a good idea unless you know what cleanup is happening behind your back.
